# Does my code prevent directory traversal in C#?

Tags: c#, directory-traversal

Please find below code that i have written:

```
private void WriteLogs(Guid _guid)
{

string varpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePath"].ToString() + @"\ErrorLogs\Logs\";

string FileName = _guid.ToString() + ".txt";

string finalPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(varpath + FileName);

if (Path.GetDirectoryName(finalPath) == Path.GetDirectoryName(varpath))
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(varpath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(varpath);
    }

    // Other code
}
}
```

Please let me know does this code prevent Directory Traversal flaw?

Comment: Looks fine to me. You can use `Path.Combine(varpath, FileName)` instead of `Path.GetFullPath` so that it joins them even if you forget the '\' character in the .config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Guid` is the only thing passed in, and a `Guid` cannot be of the form `..\..\`, I think you would be safe from a [Directory Traversal Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).

The only other input is `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePath"]`. This could be of the form `X:\Example\..`, but it could also be `X:\`, so I do not see this as a problem. Either way, you will be adding `@"\ErrorLogs\Logs\"` to the path you are writing.

I would also recommend using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx), so you dont have to get lost in `\`'s

```
string varpath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePath"]
                     .ToString(), @"ErrorLogs\Logs");
```

Answer (score -1):

this is working for me:

```
 private bool IsValidPath(string fileNamePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileNamePath))
            return false;
        var decodedPath = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fileNamePath);

        return decodedPath.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) < 0 &&
            decodedPath.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) < 0 &&
            fileNamePath.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) < 0 &&
            fileNamePath.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) < 0;
    }
```