# A Path Traversal vulnerability in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, checkmarx, secure-coding, path-traversal

I already tried these solutions

[Does my code prevent directory traversal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045117/does-my-code-prevent-directory-traversal-in-c)

[Is Path Traversal Vulnerabilities possible in my below code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383143/is-path-traversal-vulnerabilities-possible-in-my-below-code)

[How to prevent Path Traversal in .NET](https://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2018/10/how-to-prevent-path-traversal-in-net.html)

[How to avoid Directory Traversal in my code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e573dd1-8b52-4c25-89c8-1e53a08ffe2f/how-to-avoid-directory-traversal-in-my-code?forum=csharpgeneral)

But still, Checkmarx scanning giving a security issue, below is the code

```
public FileContentResult GetImageFromFilePath(string filePath)
        {
            byte[] image = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            }
            if (image == null)
                return null;
            return File(image, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

The issue is on this line of code `image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);`

Please let me known how to solve this security issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535684/224370

You should never trust user input to create a file path on the server.

Comment: Looks like an MVC Controller action? The security issue would be that someone could technically pass in `C:\link\to\private\database` and you'd return them the database. Solution is to never have an endpoint that takes a file system path, better to treat any files you serve as "assets" and keep them within the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Path Traversal* is about you building a path from the user input, mainly you have an assumption about the user input, for example, the user gives you the `year` and the `index`, and you return the right image: `$"App/Photos/${year}/${index}.png"`.

The **traversal** is that the user gives you a relative part, for example, for `year`- `../private` so that the path will be `App/private/1.png`.

To sanitize this example (and you need to think about more cases, and don't make any assumptions), you need to use `filePath.Replace("..", "")`. before using the `filePath` to access the filesystem.

Comment: It works, I was replacing `/../`, never thought to replace just `..` awesome.

Comment: it's not good enough, they can use url encoding to bypass it, `.;.` on some servers or `\..\`

Comment: Thanks @prospector, "and you need to think about more cases, and don't make any assumptions"

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66793363/452672 for sneaky encoded attempts